# How can I build an anonymous instance of a generic type?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

Consider this simple class:

```
class MyClass(p: (String, String) *) {
    val params: Map[String, String] = p.toMap
}
```

And a class that extends it:

```
class SomeOtherClass(p: (String, String) *) extends MyClass(p: _*)
```

I would like to remove the constructor from `MyClass` to avoid carrying around the initialization parameters in everything that extends it (potentially many types). Instead, I'd prefer the companion objects of the types that extend `MyClass` to inherit some sort of builder method.

```
class MyClass {
    val param = Map.empty[String, String] // some member with a default value
}

trait MyClassBuilder[A <: MyClass] {
    def apply(p: (String, String) *): A = ???
}
```

Basically `apply` should do something like this:

```
new A {
    override val param = p.toMap
}
```

Obviously, the above code cannot work. The idea is that a sub-type would be used like this:

```
class SomeOtherClass extends MyClass
object SomeOtherClass extends MyClassBuilder[SomeOtherClass] {
    // object specific things..
}
```

Then `SomeOtherClass` would rely on the inherited `apply` method for creating instances of itself. It seems something like this may be possible with reflection or macros, but I really have no idea. To be clear, I want client code like `SomeOtherClass` to require no constructor at all, which is why I want to explore creating anonymous classes on a generic type. It might not be `SomeOtherClass` that gets generated, it could be anything that extends `MyClass`.

Comment: i bet a macro is the way to go here, which would produce the boilerplate you're trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:

```
import scala.reflect._
abstract class MyClassBuilder[A <: MyClass: ClassTag] { 
  def apply() = classTag[A].runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

You may find that I didn't pass `(String, String) *` here as they're redundant for instantiation. Anyway, you have an access to the whole `A`'s instance here, so at least you can change the `param` after instantiation. It's not exactly what you want - as you seems to looking for a way to additionaly extend `SomeOtherClass` in runtime. However, runtime creation of new type in scala is impossible, but you may think of it as a prototype - just take SomeOtherClass instance and mutate once inside `apply()`:

```
import scala.reflect._
object Ctx {
  class MyClass {
    private[Ctx] var _param = Map.empty[String, String]
    def param = _param 
  }

  abstract class MyClassBuilder[A <: MyClass: ClassTag] { 
    def apply(p: (String, String) *) = {
       val i = classTag[A].runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]
       i._param = Map(p: _*)
       i
    }
  }
}

scala> class MySpecialClass extends Ctx.MyClass
defined class MySpecialClass

scala> object MySpecialBuilder extends Ctx.MyClassBuilder[MySpecialClass]
defined module MySpecialBuilder

scala> MySpecialBuilder("A" -> "b")
res12: MySpecialClass = MySpecialClass@2871ed4a

scala> res12.param
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(A -> b)
```

Otherwise you have to deal with compile-time reflection.

An interesting alternative is [extensible records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records) (Shapeless2) - they practically allow you to build new type piece by piece, but you will have to deal with `HList` instead of class there:

```
import shapeless._ ; import syntax.singleton._ ; import record._
import shapeless.ops.record.Updater
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val param = Witness("param")
val someFunW = Witness("someFun")

//defining classess (instead of "class MyClass")

type Param = Map[String, String] with KeyTag[param.T, Map[String, String]]
type SomeFun = (String => String) with KeyTag[someFunW.T, (String => String)]
type MyClass = Param :: HNil
type MySpecialClass = SomeFun :: MyClass

def someFun(s: String) = s + "A"

//defining default values (instead of "val param = ...")

def newMyClass[T <: HList : TypeTag]: T = ( 
   if (typeTag[T] == typeTag[MyClass]) 
      (param ->> Map.empty[String, String]) :: HNil 
   else if (typeTag[T] == typeTag[MySpecialClass]) 
      (someFunW ->> someFun _) :: newMyClass[MyClass]
   else HNil
).asInstanceOf[T]

//Defining builder
def buildWithParam[T <: HList: TypeTag](p: Map[String, String])(implicit ev: Updater[T, Param]) 
  = newMyClass[T] + ("param" ->> p)

scala> buildWithParam[MySpecialClass](Map("a" -> "v"))
res6: ... = <function1> :: Map(a -> v) :: HNil

scala> res6("someFun").apply("a")
res7: String = aA

scala> buildWithParam[MyClass](Map("a" -> "v"))
res8: ... = Map(a -> v) :: HNil
```

Comment: *"runtime creation of new type in scala is impossible"* -- That's pretty much the sentence I needed. This is very helpful and gives me many ideas to work with.

Comment: I'm concerned about the equality tests for type tags here - `typeTag[T] == typeTag[MyClass]`. It's not hard to end up with two different type tags for the same underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

With a type as following trait;

```scala
trait MyType {
  def params: Map[String, String]
}
```

An instance can be created by the companion object:

```scala
object MyType {
  def apply(pairs: (String, String)*): MyType = new MyType {
    val params = pairs.toMap
  }
}
//allows: MyType("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d")
```

Comment: I think he's asking how to do that with a generic

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to avoid carrying around the boilerplate of that `apply` method for sub-types.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a non-parameter constructor in the subclass like this:

```
class SomeOtherClass(p: (String, String)*) extends MyClass(p: _*) {
    def this() = this(somedefaultvalueofp)
}
```

and then use companion object with apply to apply the value from outer:

```
object SomeOtherClass {
    def apply(p: (String, String)*): SomeOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(p)
}
```

********** edited ****************

I understand now the requirement. So you might add the non-parameter constructor on your `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass(p: (String, String)*) {
    def this() = this(defaultvalueofp)
}
```

And create a class builder like you mentioned:

```
class MyClassBuilder[T <: MyClass] {
    def apply(p: (String, String)*): T = new T(p)
}
```